# How to implement Responsive Theme on Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I need to implement a responsive theme on a Drupal 6 application.

How can you do this?
What are the available theme options?
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) and [AdaptiveTheme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) are both responsive base themes that have Drupal 6 versions. If don't want to build the theme from scratch, the fastest route is to use one of those as a base theme.

Comment: Zen and Adaptive themes Drupal 6 themes are not responsive, out of the box. You have to handle your own media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The options mentioned above (Zen, AdaptiveTheme and Omega) are great, but they require you to implement a sub-theme which has it's cost - for some sites it can't be justified.

I've also had good exeperience with using Artisteer to generate a responsive theme for a Drupal 6 site - [candida](http://candida.org.il). The responsiveness is automatic, as well as the RTL support, but the resulting code is not small. But if the uniqeness of design, the low cost and speed of implementation is important, this should definitely be considered as an option.

Comment: Zen and Adaptive themes Drupal 6 themes are not responsive.